# Writing a unit test for a view with a custom base class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

We have an MVC 3 Razor web project where we specify a custom base class for our views.  In the InitializePage method of this base view class, we are doing some initialization and saving an object to the ViewBag.  This information serves as sort of a "model" for our layout pages.  One piece of information here a structured context menu that is rendered in the layout pages.  The items on this menu can change, depending on the user that is logged into our site.

My question is how I can unit test this code that runs in the base view class.  Since this code only runs when the view is rendered, do I have any choices other than mocking up a controller context under which to execute the view?  I've seen some samples on the internet about doing that and it seems like it's more trouble than it's worth.

Any thoughts would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you could garnish your question with some source code. For example the relevant source code that you are trying to unit test would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the obvious solution would be to extract that code (or at least the bulk of it) into a method of another class. Then your View class should simply pass the appropriate values to that method, making its InitializePage method sufficiently simple that it has no need for unit testing. You can unit test the method independently of the View class.